# Need help rotating an image on the canvas to face the mouseover position

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am unable to get my image to rotate to point towards the mouse pointer.
I not even sure If im going on the right direction with the code I have. So far
I can move my image around the canvas but I need it to rotate towards the mouse as I am eventually going to have it fire bullets on mouse click. Any advise will be appreciated. I'm not sure if my look function need to be in my drawPlayer function or not..

```
(function() {
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var width;
    var height;
    var speed = 8;
    var interval_id;
    var ps = [];
    var bullets = [];
    var player = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        hero: new Image(),
        size: 10,
    };
    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    }
    var moveLeft = false;
    var moveRight = false;
    var moveUp = false;
    var moveDown = false;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

    function init() {
        canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        width = canvas.width;
        height = canvas.height;
        player.hero.src = 'hero.png';
        context.drawImage(player.hero, player.x, player.y);
        window.addEventListener("keydown", activate, false);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", deactivate, false);
        window.addEventListener("mouseover", look, false);
        interval_player = window.setInterval(drawPlayer, 33);
    }

    function drawPlayer() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.drawImage(player.hero, player.x, player.y);
        if (moveRight) {
            player.x += speed;
        }
        if (moveUp) {
            player.y -= speed;
        }
        if (moveDown) {
            player.y += speed;
        }
        if (moveLeft) {
            player.x -= speed;
        }
    }
    // ******* this is where im trying to get the image to rotate ********//
    function look(event) {
        var offset = player.hero.offset();
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (player.hero.width() / 2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (player.hero.height() / 2);
        var mouse_x = event.pageX;
        var mouse_y = event.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
        player.hero.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        player.hero.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        player.hero.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        player.hero.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    }

    function activate(event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 87) {
            moveUp = true;
        } else if (keyCode === 68) {
            moveRight = true;
        } else if (keyCode === 83) {
            moveDown = true;
        } else if (keyCode === 65) {
            moveLeft = true;
        }
    }

    function deactivate(event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 87) {
            moveUp = false;
        } else if (keyCode === 68) {
            moveRight = false;
        } else if (keyCode === 83) {
            moveDown = false;
        } else if (keyCode === 65) {
            moveLeft = false;
        }
    }

    function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(interval_player);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTransform where the X axis is the normalised vector from image position to the lookat point (mouse) and the y axis is at 90 deg to the x axis (obviously)

```
function drawImagePointingAt(image,x,y,pointX,pointY){
    var xdx = pointX - x;  // get direction from image to point
    var xdy = pointY - y;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(xdx*xdx+xdy*xdy);  // get distance
    xdx /= dist;   // normalize direction
    xdy /= dist;
    // xdx,xdy is the x axis
    // -xdy, xdx is the y axis
    ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,x,y); // set transform to point at point
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
}
```

Or if you need to offset the rotation

```
function drawImagePointingAt(image,x,y,pointX,pointY, rotOffset){
    var xdx = pointX - x;  // get direction from image to point
    var xdy = pointY - y;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(xdx*xdx+xdy*xdy);  // get distance
    xdx /= dist;   // normalize direction
    xdy /= dist;
    ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,x,y); // set transform to point at point
    ctx.rotate(rotOffset);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
}
```

To restore the default transform

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

Comment: Just be careful if dist=0